# Reg_match function in informatica

Tags: informatica

I want to check for some special character set how can I implement the REG_MATCH? i want to search for some special characters like @, ^, * in a field value But no of characters can increase. I dont want to use instr function. Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any special character set. You can just specify the individual special characters in [ ]. or you can check for anything other than letters and numbers like [^a-zA-Z0-9].